# Problem with XOR : "ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found"

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, binaryfiles

This code reads bytes from two binary files and then does a byte comparison using XOR. Basically reads an odd byte from key file and then shifts that amount in text.bin file.

Even bytes in key file are bytes which must be compared with the byte in text.bin file.

Technically the way it's written it should compare the two read bytes from both bin files, but I am getting an error

```
    output = (ord(mask)^ord(a)) # XOR
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

.

```
k = open ("key.bin", "rb")
t = open ("text.bin", "rb")

k.seek(0); t.seek(0); position = 0

while 1:
        offset = k.read(1)
        mask = k.read(2)
        print(str(mask))
        
        if not offset:
                break
        if not mask:
                break
        
        shift=int(ord(offset))
        print(shift)
        position = position + shift
        
        t.seek(position)
        a = t.read(1)
        
        output = (ord(mask)^ord(a))
        print (chr(output), end="")
        
k.close() ; d.close()
```

It happens only when `mask = k.read(2)`  is reading from the 2nd byte.
'String of length 2' that could be some wrong hex string read instead of bytes?

Comment: `k.read(2)` means "read 2 bytes from k". So `mask` will be two bytes unless the file is positioned one byte from the end.

Comment: @rici Thanks. So for reading a byte from specific position I need to just use 'k.seek(2)' and then 'k.read(1)' , which would seek 2nd byte from the left and then read the one byte in that location ?

Comment: Yep, that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is causing that error because `k.read(2)` has a length of 2 and `ord` requires a length of 1.

Try this:

```
k = open ("key.bin", "rb")
t = open ("text.bin", "rb")

k.seek(0); t.seek(0); position = 0

while 1:
        offset = k.read(1)
        mask = bytes(chr(k.read(2)[1]),'utf8')
        print(str(mask))
        
        if not offset:
                break
        if not mask:
                break
        
        shift=int(ord(offset))
        print(shift)
        position = position + shift
        
        t.seek(position)
        a = t.read(1)
        
        output = (ord(mask)^ord(a))
        print (chr(output), end="")
        
k.close() ; d.close()
```